# Simple way of throwing a pop up message when button click counter is more than once in wpf xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

i have a requirement after entering credentials and clicking initialise button connections getting established and again when using different credentials and initialise it is establishing connections again that i should prevent it once connection established it should not allow again how can i achieve this simple way

tried using relay command
but it is getting complex and not working and my requirement does not need disabling the button

Comment: You don't need a converter. When you assign an ICommand to the Button.Command property then you can use the ICommand.CanExecute implementation to disable the button. For example create a IsConnected boolean property that you observe with your CanExecute implementation: `public bool CanExecute(object commandParameter) => !this.IsConnected;`. Then set the property to `true` onec the connection is established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a converter. Simply bind an `ICommand` to the `Button.Command` property. Then introduce a `IsConnected` property in your view model class to flag the current connection state and check it in your commands `CanExecute` delegate:

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // Bind to the connect button
  public ICommand ConnectCommand => new RelayCommand(ExecuteConnectCommand, CanExecuteConnectCommand);

  // Reflect the current connection state
  private bool IsConnected { get; set; }

  // Will disable the button when IsConnected returns true
  private bool CanExecuteConnectCommand(object commandParameter)
  {
    !this.IsConnected;
  }

  private void ExecuteConnectCommand(object commandParameter)
  {
    this.IsConnected = true;

    // TODO::Create connection    
  }
}
```

See [Microsoft Docs: Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) for a `RelayCommand` implementation.